# Can anyone tell me what this script in Perl do?

Tags: perl

Can anyone tell me what this script in Perl do ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my ($file, $from, $to) = @ARGV;
my $fh;
my $matching = 0;
open($fh, $file) or die $!;
while(<$fh>)
{
    if(/\Q$from\E/) { $matching = 1; }
    if($matching) { print $_; }
    if($matching && /\Q$to\E/) { last; }
}
close($fh);
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103128/13792

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reads the name of a file that you specify and prints a section of its contents.

The program **starts printing** when it finds a line that contains your ***from*** string and **stops printing** after it finds a line that contains your ***to*** string.

For example, lets say you name your program **section.pl** and have a file named **data.txt** with the following content:

```
This is line one.
This is line two.
This is line three.
This is line four.
This is line five.
This is line six.
This is line seven.
This is line eight.
This is line nine.
This is line ten.
```

And that you then run your Perl script as follows:

```
perl section.pl data.txt three seven
```

The expected output would be:

```
This is line three.
This is line four.
This is line five.
This is line six.
This is line seven.
```

Comment: Mohammed47 - Since you accepted my answer, you might consider [upvoting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) my answer as well. You can also upvote any other answer that you find helpful. And in fact, you can even later change your mind about which answer to accept. Also see [Accepting answer without upvoting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/686/243253) and the complete [Stack Exchange FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/243253).

Answer (score 0):

It reads a file and outputs everything between $from and $to.

Comment: Can you provide me with more information ?