# What does this small Perl script do?

Tags: perl

could someone explain what this small Perl script does? Thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my ($file, $from, $to) = @ARGV;
my $fh;
my $matching = 0;
open($fh, $file) or die $!;
while(<$fh>)
{
    if(/\Q$from\E/) { $matching = 1; }
    if($matching) { print $_; }
    if($matching && /\Q$to\E/) { last; }
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: Also see the answers to this [identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20294957/1497596).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This script takes three parameters:

1. Filename to read
2. Start expression
3. End expression

and prints everything between (including) start expression (second parameter) and end expression (third parameter). If you have a file with the following content:

```
111
222
333
444
555
666
```

`./script.pl filename 333 555`  will print `333`, `444` and `555`.

### More details

```
my ($file, $from, $to) = @ARGV;
```

This line assigns the command line arguments to `$file`, `$from` and `$to`. This shows/gives you the required/different command line arguments.

```
my $fh;
my $matching = 0;
```

These two lines just declare and initialize two variables used later.

```
open($fh, $file) or die $!;
```

Try to opens the first passed argument and assign it to `$fh` or exit the program if the file can't be opened.

```
while(<$fh>)
{
```

This just iterates over the file content

```
    if(/\Q$from\E/) { $matching = 1; }
```

The `\Q` and `\E` are perl specific for regular expressions. This prevents interpreting special characters as regular expressions. If the current line contains contains `$from`, `$matching` is set to one.

```
       if($matching) { print $_; }
```

if `$matching` is set, print the current line

```
    if($matching && /\Q$to\E/) { last; }
```

if `$matching` is set and `$to`is in the current line, exit the loop

```
}
close($fh);
```

close the file

Answer (score 3):

[Not an answer, just a very long comment]

It's more common to place input files at the end of the argument list. If the script had the calling convention

```
script from to file
```

instead of

```
script file from to
```

then the script could be written as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $from = shift;
my $to   = shift;
while (<>) {
   print if /\Q$from\E/ .. /\Q$to\E/;
}
```

It has the advantage of accepting input from STDIN if `file` is omitted. It also has the advantage of accepting more than one file names.

An equivalent one-liner follows:

```
perl -ne'BEGIN{($f,$t)=splice(@ARGV,0,2)} print if /\Q$f\E/../\Q$t\E/' file
```

Note: These two version find all matching sections instead of just the first. I'm not sure if that's a relevant difference or not.